# Attribute error in sharing global variable across files in PySpark project

Tags: python, pyspark

In a PySpark project containing several .py files, there is a file called `settings.py` to declare all the global variables.

```
# settings.py

def prepareMyList():
    return [2,3,4,5]

def setGlobal():
    myList = prepareMyList()
    global firstEle,secondEle,thirdEle
    firstEle = myList[0]
    secondEle = myList[1]
    thirdEle = myList[2]
```

Now, another file `doStuff.py` import global variables.

```
#doStuff.py

import settings

def incByOne():
    settings.firstEle += 1
    settings.secondEle += 1
    settings.thirdEle += 1
```

The `main.py` is the following.

```
#main.py

import settings
import doStuff

settings.setGlobal()
doStuff.incByOne()
print settings.firstEle
```

When the project is run, it is throwing an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'firstEle'`. How to get rid of this error?

Comment: does `settings.py` contain `class`?

Comment: No, `settings.py` doesn't contain `class`.

Comment: i copy-paste your code and run it, cannot reproduce your problem see here https://asciinema.org/a/8t3cwn3452bj1bzk5lgsqvb46   Is it possible your python standard library contains `settings.py` module?

Comment: Sorry. I did a silly mistake in my code. Really sorry.